# LCDディスプレイ (ACM1602N1) が Raspberry Pi 2 (modelB) で認識されない

Tags: raspberry-pi

[Raspberry Piに接続したLCD(ACM1602NI)をPythonで動かす](http://yura2.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/02/13/Raspberry_Pi%E3%81%AB%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9FLCD%28ACM1602NI%29%E3%82%92Python%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%99)

上のサイトを参考にしてlcdディスプレイ(ACM1602N1)を接続しようとしたのですが、
カーネルモジュール、i2c-bcm2708、i2c-devをロードするように設定したのち、ページにある

```
dmesg | grep i2c
```

を実行してもbcm2708_i2cの記述を見つけることができません。

代わりにi2c-bcm2835が実行されていたためそのままi2csetを実行しようとしましたが、
書き込みに失敗したため、lcdディスプレイとの相性が悪いのではないかと考えています。

配線不良は確認済みですが、bcm2708_i2cはどうすれば有効になりますか？
あるいはbcm2708とbcm2835の違いは関係ありませんか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

お使いのRapsberry piのバージョンを確認してください。

bcm2708は、Raspberry Pi Model B(Kernel 4.4系列)で使われているCPUで、Raspberry Pi 2 Model Bでは使われていません。

参考：　[メモ：Raspberry Piのボードリビジョンを判別する方法](https://qiita.com/spicemanjp/items/d702f5f89c59cc68e3b0)

また、bcm2835も、初代Raspberry Piに搭載されている、BroadcomのSoCチップ「BCM2835」と関連していると思われます。
Raspberry Pi 2 Model Bでは「BCM2836」が使われています。

＝＝
こうした事から、参考にされているサイトの情報が古いために混乱が生じているように思われます。

rapsbianを最新版に更新する。そして、下記の記事を参考にしてI2Cを有効にすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

[advanced options I2C not showing(本家(英語版)StackExchangeの記事)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63076/advanced-options-i2c-not-showing/63078?noredirect=1#68036)

Comment: 解答の手順に従ったところ、他のi2cデバイスの接続は成功しましたが、
lcdディスプレイは認識されませんでした。
接続できないのはlcdディスプレイ固有の問題のようです。

Comment: sudo i2cdetect -y 1　コマンドでI2Cのアドレスを表示させた中にLCDディスプレイのアドレスは含まれていませんか？　また、接続しているi2cデバイスとは異なるアドレスが表示されたりしていませんか？

Comment: LCDまわりの接続を確認してください。接続が不完全な場合にもi2c通信に支障が生じますから。

Comment: 確認したところ、アドレスの表示はありませんでした。
lcdディスプレイのピンは、１から順に、
GND、3.3V、10k半固定、SCL、SDA、3.3V、GND
に接続されています。
i2c(SCL/SDA)はディスプレイから直接GPIOにつなげています。